# How to pass data in an object from one activity to another activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello fellow programmers!

I am new to android and I am developing an application. I am stuck at a point where i need to pass data contained in an object from activity A to activity B. I am pasting my code below please review it and let me know if I am doing it right or wrong and suggest best practice for doing it ... Should I be passing data in an object or should I do something else? ... please suggest.

Code for Activity A

```
public MainListActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_recipes);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_listview_progressBar);

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GetRecipeData getRecipeData = new GetRecipeData();
        getRecipeData.execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),getString(R.string.no_network), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //mRecipeTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object recipeData = mRecipeAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeDetailActivity.class).putExtra("data", (Serializable) recipeData);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    return rootView;

}



private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}


private void handleRecipeData() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if(mRecipeData == null){
        handleErrors();

    }else {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mRecipeData.getJSONArray("posts");
            //mRecipePostData = new String[jsonPosts.length()];
            mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                String author = post.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR).getString("name");
                author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();

                HashMap<String, String> singleRecipePost = new HashMap<>();
                singleRecipePost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                singleRecipePost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);

                mRecipePostData.add(singleRecipePost);
                //mRecipePostData[i] = title;
            }

            String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR};
            int[] ids = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
            mRecipeAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), mRecipePostData, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);

            listView.setAdapter(mRecipeAdapter);
            mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Activity B

```
public class RecipeDetailActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = RecipeDetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String RECIPE_SHARE_HASHTAG = "#AmericanCuisines";
    private String mRecipeDataStr;

    public RecipeDetailActivityFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_detail, container, false);
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("data")){
            mRecipeDataStr = intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
            TextView details = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_detail_textView);
            details.setText(mRecipeDataStr);
        }
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.recipedetailfragment, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareRecipeIntent());
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action Provider is null?");
        }

    }

    public Intent createShareRecipeIntent(){
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mRecipeDataStr + " " + RECIPE_SHARE_HASHTAG);
        return shareIntent;
    }
}
```

I don't think so that my question is a duplicate of the referenced question because I am trying to pass serialized data an array through activities and an I am having issue in doing so ... my question is that am I doing this right ... should I be passing data contained in an object through activities ? because I will be passing alot more .. like the whole content ... images ... etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: I don't think that my question is a duplicate of the reference question ... please review my code ...

Comment: How would you like to pass your data ? By clicking the listView ?

Comment: you want pass `arrayList` to another activity ?

Comment: @JohnJoe ... sorry ..  I am saving data in a HashMap .... if you can see the the `try` block in the `handleRecipeData()` method ... you will know how I am getting the data ..

Comment: can you show all your object class ?

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't created a class for my object ... May I should not pass an object through activities .. right ?

Answer (score 0):

implement your object as Parable and pass . for more understanding read below link

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html